# Delphi. filewrite, error - E2036 Variable required

Tags: delphi

I didn't use filewrite a lot of time.

I made this procedure and received the next error: **E2036 Variable required** (on flen variable in filewrite).

```
procedure TForm1.WriteFN(const PIN: integer);
var
  lFile: integer;
  flen : integer;
begin
  flen := 2;
  lFile := FileOpen('/sys/pins', fmOpenWrite);
  try
    if filewrite(lFile, PChar(IntToStr(PIN)), flen) = -1 then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot export PIN%d', [PIN]);
  finally
    fileclose(lFile);
  end;
end;
```

How to solve this problem?

Delphi Rio, Win10.

Comment: Seems implausible. That argument doesn't expect a variable, and in any case this code provides one. It also looks like even if the code works it will write 2 bytes of an address rather than any text. And it seems odd that you'd be writing text at all. Especially if the value is less than 10. I suspect there are many problems here.

Comment: The debugger complains about the second parameter, that you want to take the address of an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `FileWrite()` is an untyped `const`. Whatever you pass to it gets passed by reference, and as such you have to give it a real variable to refer to. In this case, you can simply dereference the `PChar` pointer, that will let the parameter reference the 1st `Char` in the temporary `String` you are creating, eg:

```pascal
FileWrite(lFile, PChar(IntToStr(PIN))^, flen)
```

Note, however, that `FileWrite()` operates on raw bytes, not on string characters. You are telling `FileWrite()` to write exactly 2 bytes, which may or may not work properly, depending on which version of Delphi you are using, and what value the `PIN` contains.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.WriteFN(const PIN: integer);
var
  lFile: integer;
  flen : integer;
  s: AnsiString;
begin
  s := AnsiString(IntToStr(PIN));
  flen := Length(s);
  lFile := FileOpen('/sys/pins', fmOpenWrite);
  if lFile = -1 then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot create file to export PIN%d', [PIN]);
  try
    if FileWrite(lFile, PAnsiChar(s)^, flen) = -1 then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot write to file to export PIN%d', [PIN]);
  finally
    FileClose(lFile);
  end;
end;
```

If you are using a modern version of Delphi, consider using [`TFile.WriteAllText()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllText) instead:

```pascal
uses
  ..., System.IOUtils;

procedure TForm1.WriteFN(const PIN: integer);
begin
  try
    TFile.WriteAllText('/sys/pins', IntToStr(PIN));
  except
    Exception.RaiseOuterException(
      Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot export PIN%d', [PIN])
    );
  end;
end;
```